# k8s helm-push goal for existing Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, jkube

I am trying to configure jkube helm-push goal to upload my already existing Helm Chart to our Nexus Helm Repository...(while it seems JKube is the only one supporting Nexus)..

But it seems, jkube helm-push is dependant on resource and helm goal, wants to create its own Helm Chart, which I don't need. I just want to upload my Helm Char...

And I am always getting hte following error...

```
k8s: Error performing helm push: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: C:\wss\hasci-dds-ibis\target\classes\META-INF\jkube\kubernetes
```

Is it possible to configure helm-upload goal this way?

Thx for answers.

Comment: Pushing existing charts (YAML files) is not supported by Eclipse JKube (it's not meant to be used that way).
If you're just seeking for this functionality there are other plugins that might be more suited for the task.
The whole point of JKube is to generate, complete, or at least leverage the management of your cluster configuration files.

Comment: This plugin might be more suited for your use-case: https://github.com/kiwigrid/helm-maven-plugin

Comment: If however you're interested in leveraging the Helm chart generation so that configurations (such as image names, etc.) are inferred from your project, let me know so we can help you adapting your project to take full advantage of JKube / Kubernetes-Maven-Plugin (https://gitter.im/eclipse/jkube)

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin supports only Artifactory and Chart Museum and we are using Nexus. The charm for me, for your plugin, it seems you are supporting Nexus upload.